# Change body content of custom component

Tags: jsf, custom-component

I would like to implement a custom jsf tag that will take the text between the opening and closing tag, perform an operation on it, and return it.  For example,

```
<l:lessInline>
.list-results {
    .search-result {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
</l:lessInline>
```

I need this to take the content of `<l:lessInline>` and pass it through a LESS compiler, and then render it between `<style>` tags.

I have created a JSF 2.2 FacesComponent which successfully renders Hello World inside `<style>` tags:

```
@FacesComponent (value = "inlineLess")
public class InlineLessComponent extends UIComponentBase
{

    @Override
    public String getFamily ()
    {
        return "inlineLessComponent";
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin (final FacesContext context) throws IOException
    {
        final ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter ();
        writer.startElement ("style", this);
        writer.write ("Hello World");
        writer.endElement ("style");
        writer.flush ();
    }

}
```

What I am unable to figure out is how to 'read' and then replace the stuff inside the tag.  Currently, anything 'inside' the component tags is left in place beneath the rendered element. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body is rendered during `encodeChildren()`. Just temporarily replace the response writer with a local buffer like below so you can capture the rendered output without it being written through.

```
ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
context.setResponseWriter(writer.cloneWithWriter(output));

try {
    super.encodeChildren(context);
}
finally {
    context.setResponseWriter(writer);
}

String body = output.toString();
// ... Manipulate it here if necessary.
writer.write(manipulatedBody);
```